# iOS application is using Malloc function instead of calloc

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am new in ionic development. I am developing a ionic 3 cordova application for iOS. The test team reported that the ipa is using Malloc function instead of calloc. They recommended to avoid use of such function in the binary, alternatives such as calloc function can be used as it initializes the allocated memory to zero and therefore provides more security. 
Please help me to fix this issue.

The app is using ionic 3 and cordova. These are plugin list using in the app 
cordova-plugin-actionsheet 2.3.3 "ActionSheet" 
cordova-plugin-advanced-http 3.1.0 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter 1.1.3 "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter"
cordova-plugin-app-version 0.1.12 "AppVersion"
cordova-plugin-badge 0.8.8 "Badge"
cordova-plugin-camera 5.0.2 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-datepicker 0.9.3 "DatePicker"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-ios-camera-permissions 1.2.0 "iOS Permissions"
cordova-plugin-market 1.2.0 "Market"
cordova-plugin-network-information 3.0.0 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-toast 2.7.2 "Toast"
cordova.plugins.diagnostic 6.0.3 "Diagnostic"
onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.11.4 "OneSignal Push Notifications"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 8.1.0 "BarcodeScanner"

Comment: This is almost certainly a [false positive](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/679).  To address it you would need to find where in all of those plugins (and potentially in the core Ionic code) `malloc` is being used and either convince the maintainers to modify the code or modify it yourself.  Does your app deal with confidential information? Remember that your iOS app is running in a sandbox and uses Address Space Layout Randomisation.

Comment: I found that cordova-plugin-file and cordova-plugin-device use malloc function. Do I need to modify those line using calloc? Please advise.

Comment: You could. I wouldn't. To really answer thT question you need to look at the code, see what it does with the memory block that it mallocs and see if it warrants the hassle of modifying the code (and therefore having to maintain your own fork of those modules) and what the performance implications might be of using `calloc`. I would go back to the test team and ask them to justify that work instead of them just relying on some brainless automatic scan

Comment: I can tell you that there will be thousands of places where `malloc` is used in the Apple frameworks and you have no visibility and no control over it

Comment: For example, if you look at Cordova-plug-in-device, it mallocs a block of size `size`, immediately writes `size` bytes to it, extracts the platform string and then frees the block. There is absolutely no benefit to changing that to `calloc` and no risk from using `malloc`

Comment: Similarly with the file plug-in. The malloced memory is immediately overwritten. `calloc` would not do anything except be slower